# Telegram API получить список чатов

Tags: java, telegram

Я делаю клиент для Telegram на Java с использованием официальной библиотеки [TDLib](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib), т.е. ее binding'а для Java. [Пример](https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/master/example/java/org/drinkless/tdlib/example/Example.java), скопированный в мой проект из официального репозитория библиотеки, работает без нареканий.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы отслеживать появление новых чатов (например, кто-то пользователей создал новый групповой чат на N-человек и пригласил в него меня в том числе). Реализовать это несложно. Достаточно в цикле делать запрос вида (или по расписанию с использованием аннотации `@Scheduled` в Spring):

```
client.send(new TdApi.GetChats(
            offsetOrder, 
            offsetChatId, 
            limit - chatList.size()), 
            () -> { ... });
```

Но мне хотелось бы не опрашивать сервер на предмет появления новых чатов, а получать уведомления о таких событиях, что-нибудь наподобие:

```
client.subscribe(EventType.NewChat, () -> { ... } , () -> { ... });
```

Я пробовал искать подходящие методы в Java-классах, но безуспешно (потому что Javadoc-ов равно как и нормально названных параметров нет - все же это binding к библиотеке, написанной на C). В собственно нативном классе [Client](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1_client.html) я не нашел упоминания о получении уведомлений.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли это в принципе? И в каком направлении копать?

---

P.S. Просьба не пинать сильно. Я гуглил на эту тему. Но основном результаты о Telegram **Bot** API. У меня же задача сделать именно клиента (который будет работать на сервере и складывать активность Telegram в БД PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось просто.

В упомянутом ранее [примере](https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/master/example/java/org/drinkless/tdlib/example/Example.java) из официального репозитория как раз используются обновления, т.е. не нужно "пинговать" сервер на пример новых событий. Их обработчик указывается при создании клиента:

```
    client = Client.create(new TelegramService.UpdatesHandler(), null, null);
```

В `UpdatesHandler`'e уже был код, который следит за появлением нового чата:

```
    @Override
    public void onResult(TdApi.Object object) {
        switch (object.getConstructor()) {
            // ...
            case TdApi.UpdateNewChat.CONSTRUCTOR: {

                TdApi.UpdateNewChat updateNewChat = (TdApi.UpdateNewChat) object;
                TdApi.Chat chat = updateNewChat.chat;
                synchronized (chat) {
                    chats.put(chat.id, chat);

                    long order = chat.order;
                    chat.order = 0;
                    setChatOrder(chat, order);
                }
                break;
            }
        // ...
```

Можно также обрабатывать другие события, например, следить за входящими сообщениями:

```
            case TdApi.UpdateNewMessage.CONSTRUCTOR:
                System.out.println(">>> TdApi.UpdateNewMessage.CONSTRUCTOR()");
                break;
```

Более подробно об этом написано в документации в разделе [Handling updates](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/getting-started#handling-updates).